# mat-icon in multiple mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

how fix issue with mat-icon in mat-select(multiple), after adding mat-icon and selecting option mat-icon value also displaying in selected values see attach image
[mat-select-list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDwBM.png)

[selecte items list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H5A4.png)

```
<mat-form-field class="p-8 w-100-p" fxFlex>
          <mat-select multiple
            [(ngModel)]="documentCategory">
            <mat-option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of documentTagsList">
              {{item}}
              <span fxFlex = '1 0 auto'></span>
              <mat-icon class="mat-24 mt-12 float-right"  (click)='deleteDocumentTag(item)'>delete</mat-icon>
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You want to show mat-icon along with selected values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mat-select-trigger` to customize what you show in the mat-select trigger text. For more information, check [Angular Material: Custom Trigger Text](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#customizing-the-trigger-label)

```
<mat-form-field class="p-8 w-100-p" fxFlex>    
  <mat-select multiple [(ngModel)]="documentCategory">
      <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="documentCategory">
         <span *ngFor="let category of documentCategory; last as isLast">
           {{category + (isLast ? '' : ', ')}}
         </span>
      </mat-select-trigger>
      <mat-option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of documentTagsList">
         {{item}}
         <span fxFlex = '1 0 auto'></span>
         <mat-icon class="mat-24 mt-12 float-right"  (click)='deleteDocumentTag(item)'>delete</mat-icon>
      </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: that's help, just added replace and and bracket to (isLast ? '' : ', ') 
`<mat-select-trigger *ngIf="card.documentCategory">
                   <span *ngFor="let category of card.documentCategory; last as isLast">
                      {{category.replace('delete','') + (isLast ? '' : ', ')}}
                    </span>
</mat-select-trigger>`